# rotation inside OpenGL shading language

Tags: opengl, 3d, rotation, quaternions, fragment-shader

I wonder if there is a way how to compute a rotationmatrix using OpenGL shading language, i.e. doing the calculation using a shader. (Optimally by two given vectors using quaternionpower.)

Some background:
I have a project, where I want to implement a lightfield on the vertices of a 3D mesh (+interpolation) that requires vectors to be in local coordinates (Torrance, Lafortune, etc...).

Now this requires the calculation of a rotation matrix quite a number of times(Number of vertices should be scalable). This could be done somewhere in normal sourcecode using normal CPU, but I was hoping to find a way to use the power of the graphicscard to do this job for me.

Till now I could find any hint in the OpenGL manual itself nor anywhere else...

Comment: And what about implementing it, just like it would be implemented on CPU, for example in C++, but in GLSL?

Comment: Generally: if the matrix is invariant during the shader runtime, you may compute it on the CPU and pass it into the shader as a uniform (attend column/row major layouts). otherwise you calculate it in the shader, thus on the GPU, which is anyway better suited for vector ops. For a more specific  answer, the question needs to made more specific.

Comment: @Matso - I would do this, but was hoping for some better ideas here ...

Comment: @decitype_auto - the hint helped me a lot! Finally I have to calculate the rotation many many times, but I don't need to calculate it for any frame - there was my thinking mistake! ... Concerning your second answer: Synthesizing a rotation matrix is unfortunately not a "vector" (i.e. linear) operation, that is probably why it is not implemented...